# Create PV in AKS with terraform Using the default storage class

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, kubernetes-pvc

I want to create with terraform a PVC in AKS cluster using the default storage class that comes with the AKS cluster. Here the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv)

If I do `kubectl get sc` i´m getting:

[image]

But not sure how to use terraform code to refere them. Was trying with:

```
resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume" "volume" {
  metadata {
    name = "${var.pv_name}"
  }
  spec {
    capacity {
      storage = "50Gi"
    }
    access_modes = ["ReadWriteOnce"]
    persistent_volume_source {
      azure_disk {
        caching_mode  = "None"
        disk_name     = "managed-premium"
        kind          = "Managed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but It´s saying: `The argument "data_disk_uri" is required, but no definition was found.`

I get that, it´s indicating that I should enter the URL of the disk from Azure portal, But in this case I didn´t created a disk in azure, using the storage class provided by AKS.
Has somebody was able to create this in AKS before?

Comment: I think it should be visible in the Azure console anyway.

Comment: Even the The default storage class provisions a standard SSD Azure disk. I don't think we can create the AKS with Storage Class only.  AFAIK PVC is depedent on Storage class and Storage class depedent on Disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create the PV with storage class only, because A StorageClass provides a way for administrators to describe the "classes" of storage they offer. Each StorageClass has a provisioner that determines what volume plugin is used for provisioning PVs. This field must be specified.

The Volume Plugin would be `Azure Disk`, `Azure Files`, `AWSElasticBlockStore` and many more you can refer the [**document**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) for available volume plugin for Storage Class.

Each StorageClass contains the fields provisioner, parameters, and reclaimPolicy, which are used when a PersistentVolume belonging to the class needs to be dynamically provisioned.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp3
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

The default storage class provisions a standard SSD Azure disk. A persistent volume claim (PVC) is used to automatically provision storage based on a storage class. In this case, a PVC can use one of the pre-created storage classes to create a standard or premium Azure managed disk.

So , Based on above Statement you need to create volume plugin like Azure DIsk, There is no option to Create PV in AKS with storage class without any volume plugin

***Reference : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/***